# getValues/setValues creates #ERROR when cell contains only equals sign

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that copies three sheets from the same file to pdfs then emails them as attachments.

On the problem sheet there's a line that has 5 cells - (1) cost of transportation formula, (2) a plus sign, (3) a cost of meals formula, (4) an equals sign, and (5) a total cost formula

Cell (4) shows correctly when viewed on screen, printed, or downloaded as a pdf. When running the script, this cell shows as #ERROR because it thinks that it's an incomplete formula. I've changed the cell contents to start with an apostrophe and set the formatting to plain text, but the issue persists.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    var sourcesheet = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(SheetNames[i]);
    var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange(SheetRanges[i]);
    var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
    var data = sourcesheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export"); 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = sourcesheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
    var destrange = sheet.getRange(SheetRanges[i]);
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
    newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').hideSheet();

    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    attachments[i] = {fileName:SheetNames[i] + '.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
}
```

Comment: Use copy instead.